# Can I remove a specific number from a list, but only once?

Tags: python, list

So I want to remove the first occurence of a number, not all of the occurences.

example:
numbers = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1]

I want to remove the first 2 in the list like this:

numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1]

Comment: Remove the first occurrence of every number? Your question and example seems to be asking to remove just the first 2.

Comment: Do you know the position of the first "2"?

Answer (score 2):

```
numbers = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1]
numbers.remove(2)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just find index of first occurrence using index and delete it

```
numbers = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1]
del numbers[numbers.index(2)]

print(numbers) # -> [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 1]
```